Show integral identity
Given a measure space $(\Omega,A,\mu)$ and a non-negative measurable function $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, show that
$\int\ f d\mu = \int_{[0,\infty)} \mu(\{f>x\}) d\lambda(x)$.
So I think you show this first for simple functions i.e. $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\alpha_{i}\mathbb{1}_{A_i}$
with $\alpha_i$ non-negative and $A_i$ measurable.
That was difficult but I was at least able to show it for $\alpha\mathbb{1}_A$
using the calculation:
$\int\alpha\mathbb{1}_A d\mu = \alpha \mu(A)$ and also
$\int_{[0,\infty)} \mu(\{\alpha\mathbb{1}_A>x\}) d\lambda(x)$
= $\int_{[0,\alpha)} \mu(\{\alpha\mathbb{1}_A>x\}) d\lambda(x)$
=$\int_{[0,\alpha)} \mu(A) d\lambda(x)$
= $\alpha \mu(A)$. Can i somehow from that easily conclude that the desired equality holds for all functions of the type $ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\alpha_{i}\mathbb{1}_{A_i}$ (or maybe using a similar calculation?).
If yes, I would try to show it for all non-negative functions by trying to show it for the limits of those simple functions.
Any tips/ideas are appreciated.

Do you believe that $(x,y) \mapsto \chi_{{f(y) > x}}$ is measurable? If so, Tonelli is your friend.

First of all, that's a great tip. Just to be sure, let me write it all down
So let $h:\Omega \times [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}, h(\omega,x) = 1 $ if $f(\omega)> x$ and $0$ otherwise be the function you suggested. We actually showed earlier in this advanced probality theory course that this is indeed measurable. It is also non-negative so Tonellis Theorem is applicable. Using it one has:
$\int_{[0,\infty)} \mu(f>x)d\lambda(x) = \int_{[0,\infty)}\int_{\Omega}h(\omega,x)d\mu(\omega)d\lambda(x) 
=\int_{\Omega}\int_{[0,\infty)}h(\omega,x)d\lambda(x)d\mu(\omega)
=\int_{\Omega} f d\mu   $
where the last equality holds because for all $\omega \in \Omega$ we have that:
$\int_{[0,\infty)} h(\omega,x) d\lambda(x) = \int_{[0,\infty)}\chi_{\{f(\omega)>x\}}d\lambda(x) = \int_{[0,f(\omega))}d\lambda(x) = f(\omega)$
This is way easier than the way I tried it first with simple functions.

That's the trick
